# Evaluating into two or more lists

Tags: python, list

Howdy, codeboys and codegirls!

I have came across a simple problem with seemingly easy solution. But being a Python neophyte I feel that there is a better approach somewhere.

Say you have a list of mixed strings. There are two basic types of strings in the sack - ones with "=" in them (a=potato) and ones without (Lady Jane). What you need is to sort them into two lists.

The obvious approach is to:

```
for arg in arguments:
   if '=' in arg:
       equal.append(arg)
   else:
       plain.append(arg)
```

Is there any other, more elegant way into it? Something like:

```
equal = [arg for arg in arguments if '=' in arg]
```

but to sort into multiple lists?

And what if you have more than one type of data?

Comment: I think your obvious approach is perfectly good, and much more readable than many of the answers suggested so far!

Comment: Indeed, I find list comprehensions are one of the most elegant features of python which I constantly crave whilst writing C++! 2 of those are much nicer than any of the answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
for arg in arguments:
    lst = equal if '=' in arg else plain
    lst.append(arg)
```

or (holy ugly)

```
for arg in arguments:
    (equal if '=' in arg else plain).append(arg)
```

A third option: Create a class which offers `append()` and which sorts into several lists.

Comment: I find more readable the form `list = ('=' in arg) and equal or plain`.

Comment: I think "a if cond else b" is very readable English; I just don't like to put too much into a single line.

Comment: and it should be `else plain`.

Comment: @giorgian, what a truly **horrible** idea you have there: when `equal` is empty (i.e. at the start) your "more readable" form ALWAYS gives `plain`, so nothing will ever be appended to `equal` -- so much for "more readable" (eek!-).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this:

```
import itertools
f = lambda x: '=' in x
groups = itertools.groupby(sorted(data, key=f), key=f)
for k, g in groups:
    print k, list(g)
```

Comment: I thought he asked for elegant

Comment: The sorting makes it nlog(n) while a simpler O(n) solution exists.

Answer (score 3):

I would just go for two list comprehensions. While that does incur some overhead (two loops on the list), it is more Pythonic to use a list comprehension than to use a for. It's also (in my mind) much more readable than using all sorts of really cool tricks, but that less people know about.

Answer (score 2):

```
def which_list(s):
    if "=" in s: 
        return 1
    return 0

lists = [[], []]

for arg in arguments:
    lists[which_list(arg)].append(arg)

plain, equal = lists
```

If you have more types of data, add an if clause to `which_list`, and initialize `lists` to more empty lists.

Comment: which_list can be a lot simpler - see my answer.  Otherwise, our answers are pretty close.

Comment: Indeed, it can be, but the OP asked about the case of more than two possibilities, which I wanted to deal with in the initial design.

Comment: In that case, I think a dictionary of lists would be clearer. The list indices are meaningless.

Comment: Yes, a dict of lists is better!

Answer (score 2):

I would go for Edan's approach, e.g.

```
equal = [arg for arg in arguments if '=' in arg]
plain = [arg for arg in arguments if '=' not in arg]
```

Answer (score 2):

I read somewhere here that you might be interested in a solution that
will work for *more* than two identifiers (equals sign and space).

The following solution just requires you update the `uniques` set with
anything you would like to match, the results are placed in a dictionary of lists
with the identifier as the key.

```
uniques = set('= ')
matches = dict((key, []) for key in uniques)

for arg in args:
    key = set(arg) & uniques
    try:
        matches[key.pop()].append(arg)
    except KeyError:
        # code to handle where arg does not contain = or ' '.
```

Now the above code assumes that you will only have a single match for your identifier
in your `arg`. I.e that you don't have an `arg` that looks like this `'John= equalspace'`.
You will have to also think about how you would like to treat cases that don't match anything in the set (`KeyError` occurs.)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use the `filter` function, although it's not the most efficient solution.
Example:

```
>>> l = ['a=s','aa','bb','=', 'a+b']
>>> l2 = filter(lambda s: '=' in s, l)
>>> l3 = filter(lambda s: '+' in s, l)
>>> l2
['a=s', '=']
>>> l3
['a+b']
```

Answer (score 1):

I put this together, and then see that Ned Batchelder was already on this same tack.  I chose to package the splitting method instead of the list chooser, though, and to just use the implicit 0/1 values for False and True.

```
def split_on_condition(source, condition):
    ret = [],[]
    for s in source:
        ret[condition(s)].append(s)
    return ret

src = "z=1;q=2;lady jane;y=a;lucy in the sky".split(';')

plain,equal = split_on_condition(src, lambda s:'=' in s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is the best one. For sorting just into two lists it can't get clearer than that. If you want it to be a one-liner, encapsulate it in a function:

```
def classify(arguments):
    equal, plain = [], []
    for arg in arguments:
        if '=' in arg:
            equal.append(arg)
        else:
            plain.append(arg)
    return equal, plain


equal, plain = classify(lst)
```